# XCode UI Test fails 'element not found' check

Tags: xcode, xcode-ui-testing, xcode8

I'm writing classes extending from `XCTestCase` to do some UI Automation tests. In my test base class I have something like:

```
- (BOOL)isOnLoginFormView
{
    return self.app.textFields[@"User ID"] != nil && self.app.secureTextFields[@"Password"] != nil &&  self.app.buttons[@"<b>Login</b>"] != nil;
}
```

I use this method in another test case method. In a situation when the login form is not present it should continue with some other code (checking for the existence of another view) but my UI test fails in any case if the above method return `NO`. Is there anything I can do so the test is not failing if the above method returns `NO`? Optimally the test cases should only fail if I fail them explicitly with an assert.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! I figured out it works with this:

```
return self.app.textFields[@"User ID"].exists && self.app.secureTextFields[@"Password"].exists &&  self.app.buttons[@"<b>Login</b>"].exists;
```